# Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). errorr

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, error-handling

Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

this error happen when i i want use skit_learn or smote

only one column is float .there is no non-nan on dataset

what should i do?

i tried many times to fix but i cant[image]

Comment: Add your data and code as text. Not as an image. Based on the formula of `minmaxscaler` maybe you have division by zero.

Comment: @I'mahdi dear mahdi ,this error happen  even i do smote for imbalance data

Comment: Add a small representation of your data and your code that produces errors So I or others can help you.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/joniarroba/noshowappointments

Comment: @I'mahdi i send the code  to your email dear mahdi